# AttributeError while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a website, I have got this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

at

```
---> 12             for x in soup.select("div.site-content")]
```

The code used is:

```
rq = req.get("https://stopcensura.net/category/cronaca")
soup = BeautifulSoup(rq.content, 'html.parser')
scrape_info = [(x.h3.a.text, x.time.text)
            for x in soup.select("div.site-content")]
```

I would like to get infnormation on title (`entry-title`), date (`class="date"`), the author (`<div class="by-author vcard author">... </div>`),and the content (`div class="entry-content"`).
I think the problem may be in selecting the right tags, but I am not sure of this.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What page is `num`?

Comment: sorry, this code is part of a crawler. I am going to delete that part. I would like to scrape all the pages in section called 'cronaca'; however, since it is not working for one page, there does not make sense to use num for all the other pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the CSS Selectors a bit to get the correct output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://stopcensura.net/category/cronaca"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".entry-header"):
    print(tag.select_one(".entry-title a").text)
    print(tag.select_one(".date a").text)
    print(tag.select_one(".by-author a").text)
    print(tag.find_next(class_="entry-content").text.strip())
    print("-" * 50)
```

Output:

```
Manifestanti inscenano corteo funebre a Napoli: “Conte hai ucciso l’Italia” (VIDEO)
2 Nov 2020
Redazione
“L’Italia che lotta non si ferma: decimo giorno di protesta. Numerosi cittadini a Napoli protestano contro…
--------------------------------------------------
Foggia, immigrato irrompe in casa armato: sprangate ad una famiglia italiana
2 Nov 2020
Redazione
FOGGIA – La serenità di una famiglia foggiana è stata interrotta da un immigrato 21enne, irregolare…
--------------------------------------------------
Decine di agenti per chiudergli locale. Titolare: “Sono un lavoratore, non un camorrista”
1 Nov 2020
Redazione
“Dopo sei giorni di eroica disobbedienza civile il ristorante Bistrot Bonaccorsi a Bologna viene chiuso con…
--------------------------------------------------
Roma, popolo in marcia verso il Parlamento: agenti caricano i manifestanti (VIDEO)
31 Ott 2020
Redazione
“L’Italia non si ferma: ottavo giorno di proteste. Roma, Campo dei Fiori, cittadini in marcia pacifica…
--------------------------------------------------
Strage di Nizza, leader islamico: “Se i fedeli si arrabbiano, poi succedono tante cose” (VIDEO)
31 Ott 2020
Redazione
Le parole del leader della comunità musulmana di Roma, Ahah Mohammed Taifur Rahman, che ieri durante…
--------------------------------------------------
Proteste a Firenze: “Non siamo fascisti, abbiamo votato per quei pezzi di mer** del Pd” (VIDEO)
31 Ott 2020
Redazione
“Proteste a Firenze contro lockdown e Governo Conte. Manifestanti tuonano contro l’informazione di regime: “Non siamo…
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much for  your help, MendelG. In this case, if I wanted to put into one function, what should I return as fields? I would like to use the code for other websites, so I was wondering how to return the tags to create with the results a dataframe. Thanks again

Comment: @LucaDiMauro I'm not to familiar with Pandas to help you.