# Error while creating a new dataframe using scraped fields

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website and I am trying to get some information like time/date, author, title and content as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get("https://stopcensura.net/category/immigrazione/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.select(".entry-header"):
        print(tag.select_one(".entry-title a").text)
        print(tag.select_one(".date a").text)
        print(tag.select_one(".by-author a").text)
        print(tag.find_next(class_="entry-content").text.strip())

    return tag.select_one(".entry-title a").text, tag.select_one(".date a").text, tag.select_one(
        ".by-author a").text, tag.find_next(class_="entry-content").text.strip()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 78)]
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.extend(f.result())
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            allin, columns=["Date/Time", "Author", "HL", "Content"])
```

The first part of code was updated following the answer that I got here: [AttributeError while scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653390/attributeerror-while-scraping)
The second part of code has been added later looking for some way to scrape multiple pages.

I would need to run this code through all the pages (this explains why I am considering         `r=req.get("https://stopcensura.net/category/immigrazione/page/{}/".format(num)))`

I tried to follow some answers in the community discussing about similar problems/topics, but without success as I am still getting an error:

> ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 118 columns

where 4 columns are date/time, author, title and content.

If you could help to understand how to create a dataframe with the information scraped I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: added all the code.The second part may contain errors which cause the issue

Comment: I reformatted the code, I think we're still missing some imports.

Comment: it is the whole code.

Comment: _it is the whole code._ I get: _NameError: name 'ThreadPoolExecutor' is not defined_ As an aside, have you checked the contents of `allin` before the DF is created?

Comment: it only misses the library: from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: The most basic fix is one line: Change `allin.extend(f.result())` to `allin.append(f.result())`. I think the order of the columns does not correspond to the order of the data which is returned, but that's a minor issue. Also, IIUC `requests.Session` is not thread-safe, so your best bet is to make some larger changes to this code.

Comment: Thanks a lot AMC. I will try to apply your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside the looping, if I understand your correctly, you may be looking form something like this:

```
columns = ['title','date','author','content']
rows = []
for tag in soup.select(".entry-header"):
    row = []
    row.append(tag.select_one('h2.entry-title a').text)
    row.append(tag.select_one('div.date a').text)    
    row.append(tag.select_one('div.by-author a').text)
    row.append(tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.select_one('p').text)
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    title                                               date           author          content
0   Attentato Nizza, Capuozzo: “Sui barconi non c’...   30 Ott 2020     Redazione   Attentato di Nizza. Il pensiero di Toni Capuoz...
1   Generale Milillo: “Governo ripensi politica mi...   30 Ott 2020     Redazione   Attentatore di Nizza sbarcato a Lampedusa. L’i...
2   Parroco contro Bergoglio: “È in corso un’invas...   30 Ott 2020     Redazione   “E’ in atto un’invasione da parte dei musulman...
3   Ammiraglio: “Da Tunisia centinaia di terrorist...   29 Ott 2020     Redazione   “Siamo oramai arrivati a una situazione che no...
4   Migranti si giocano il pocket money nelle sale...   23 Ott 2020     Redazione   “L’Inps: “Gli immigrati servono a pagare le pe...
5   Sbarchi incessanti nonostante Covid: altri 253...   21 Ott 2020     Redazione   Sbarchi a raffica a Lampedusa nelle ultime ore...
```